# What does 'String...' mean?

Tags: java, language-construct

In the code:

```
public interface ProductInterface {

    public List<ProductVO> getProductPricing(ProductVO product, ProductVO prodPackage, String... pricingTypes) throws ServiceException;

}
```

What does

```
String... pricingTypes
```

mean? What type of construct is this?

Comment: [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Check the [arguments tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) to learn about varargs.

Answer (score 11):

It is called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). It works for any type as long as it's the *last* argument in the signature.

Basically, any number of parameters are put into an array. This does not mean that it is equivalent to an array.

A method that looks like:

```
void foo(int bar, Socket baz...)
```

will have an *array* of Socket (in this example) called baz.

So, if we call `foo(32, sSock.accept(), new Socket())` we'll find an array with two Socket objects.

Calling it as `foo(32, mySocketArray)` will **not** work as the type is *not* configured to take an array. However, if the signature is a varargs of arrays you can pass one or more arrays and get a two-dimensional array. For example, `void bar(int bar, PrintStream[] baz...)` can take multiple arrays of PrintStream and stick them into a single `PrintStream[][]`.

Oddly enough, due to the fact that arrays are objects, `Object... foo` can take any number of arrays.

Answer (score 4):

It's a vararg - variable argument.  You can pass a value of that type as many times as you want and the caller gets it as an array.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html